Seeking a New Method for Obtaining a Concise Determinant Result
I know how to compute this determinant, but my method yields a result that is not concise.
My approach involves multiplying the ( j )-th column by $(-\frac{c_{j-1}}{b_j})$ and adding it to the ( (j-1) )-th column for $( n \leq j \leq 2 )$(from column n-1 to column 1). This transforms the determinant into an upper triangular form, where the result is the product of the main diagonal elements. However, I find that after these operations, the element in the (1,1) position of the upper triangular determinant is too complex, resulting in a non-concise solution.
I am seeking a method to obtain a more succinct result. The problem hint suggests using a method involving reducing the determinant's order.
$$\left| A \right| = 
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \ldots & a_{n-1} & a_n \\
c_1 & b_2 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & c_2 & b_3 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & b_{n-1} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & c_{n-1} & b_n
\end{vmatrix}$$

Try Laplace expansion.
